# Where should I manage the coherency of my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I would like to understand the advantages/disadvantages in managing the coherency of my database in code as opposed to using SQL features.

Just to explain: 
Coherency means that if I have users, and each user has albums and each album has images, then deleting a user means deleting (or soft deleting) all albums and images. This could also mean having images having sequential ids per user and per album on top of their primary keys.

In code means using "on inserted, deleted, updated" events in my framework code (Eloquent for example)

sql features mean using cascade, trigger, etc.

People have complained that this is opinion based, but it isn't. Applying only code rules and no constraints may cause inconsistency if the mysql shell is used-that's a fact. 
Also if someone has links to best practices and references, that would be also good, I am really interested in knowing what the devs at google do for example - again.not.opinions.but.facts.

Edit: spelling, formatting, appeal to reopen based on factual phrasing of question.

Comment: Do it in code, and your database is screwballed the instance anybody uses the MySQL command line to do a delete

Comment: @MarkBaker it seems that you may have interesting input on the subject, can you write an answer with a few more? As you can see, there is a pro code answer with 3 bullets.

Comment: If the DB were an Object, where would you expect that Object's state to be managed?  In other Objects, or within it self?  In principle I believe that an Object should maintain its own state and ensure the integrity of that state.  In the same way I expect a Database to manage its own state, as if it were simply a remote object.  This enables separation of code, has benefits with multiple clients connecting, and directs code in a direction that makes management of different versions (of both the client and the DB) more sustainable.  In my opinion.

Comment: Im not asking for opinions, I'm asking for advantages and disadvantages, like the question says , which is entirely factual. Why is thus question on hold?

Comment: This is not the right venue for this kind of question, so I doubt this will get re-opened. In a nutshell, though... In the DB: harder to write (i.e. procedure language, triggers, etc.), but once that's done you get to use the same logic absolutely everywhere, as well as much tighter security and access control to the data. Out of the DB: slightly easier to write and scale (you can shard the work across many front-ends), but messier to deploy, and prone to corruption because one might screw around with direct DB access or forget to properly lock the data when dealing with concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A Laravel Answer

Since you tagged this question with [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) and also [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) I'm going to give you an answer that supports the Laravel development style. Laravel supports Eloquent ORM and Database Migrations through Artisan. This will allow you to keep this "coherency" within your code, rather than strictly on the DB.

### ORM

There are tons of resources available for understanding what ORM is and how it works. Laravel uses [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) and allows you to enforce both relationships and rules for your models and their elements.

### Migrations

Using [migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) we can build our database in a way that makes sense with our models, while simultaneously keeping it portable between most databases (MySQL vs. Postgres).

### Multi-Developer Applications

Applications that are being developed by more than one developer will need a way to keep in sync. If one developer decides to add a table with certain constraints, this needs to be communicated to the rest of the team. Adding rules directly to the database can lead to issues when communicating with the other team members and will cause headaches. Instead, use migrations and ORM to both describe what's being changed, and why. Migrations will allow any other developers to simply 'migrate' their DB to the newest version and stay in sync.

### Conclusion

To compare points with some of the other listed answers:

- **All code is *still* in one place.** Migrations and Models are made in PHP and kept in your project repo.
- It's already **enforced within the application** thanks to both DB rules from ORM and Migrations.
- **Practical** as there is plenty of documentation and help regarding these topics within the Laravel community and it's arguably the "Official" method of going about this.
- **KISS** This will keep everything simple especially if you are dealing with other developers and environments as it's very portable.

Comment: It feels like you are pro code, correct? The use of migrations is necessary to versiomize db changes, but the question remains: should I add a migration that adds a constraint or should I push code changes on the table /model file?

Comment: Good question. I wasn't clear.  I meant to imply that by solely using migrations (written in PHP within laravel) you are adding database constraints and relationships to the database, but only *through* actual code. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It depends, but here you have some ideas:

- Logic placed at DB

  - More easy for developers (you put it on DB and forget)
- Logic placed at Code

  - If you want to be pure Object Oriented, the object should have all business logic.
  - If in the future you change persistence motor (to Object oriented DB, for example, you'll need this logic in code)
- Placed in Both:

  - For me, the better solution because to place it in DB is low cost and, for me, Object oriented coding going to be not coupled with persistence (ORM).

Jordi Martínez

Answer (score 1):

This is a much debated topic. I have a completely different opinion as most other devs (as seen above). It still might be worth checking this out:

I will allways manage coherency of all my data inside the application code and use no foreign keys or other contraints.

These are the reasons:

- **One code location**. All of my logic should be in one place. If you spread logic over more than one place, devs will tend to forget about them in the future and this will seriously cripple coherency of the database. Same reason why I will never have stored procedures btw.
- **Still needed in application** If you do coherency checks in your database, you will STILL have to check same constraints in your application. You need to do this to allow the application to display nice errors to the user and enforce logic constraints. So if you need them anyways, why replicate same rules in the db again? THis leads to redundant logic, which leads to easily forgotten logic, which leads to crippled coherency.
- **extremely impractical** Ever tried to do a database dump and then reimport it into your database? You will have a hard time. Tables often violate constraints during import, different systems do not allow to ignore constraints during import. And administering fixes to data on the fly via a database tool can also be a serious pain. So it seriously affects your admin performance in a bad way.

Yes, there may be reasons to use constraints anyways, but they have to be really strong reasons if they can counter above three points.

Comment: One code location is not necessarily ideal. There is a reason we break out stuff. Referential integrity is not the same as logic.

Your errors can be displayed without explicitly doing coherence checks if your error handling is done right with regards to your query execution.

If your constraints are well-defined, you will never have a hard time importing a database.

Comment: Ok, let's call it "one location for dev stuff". of course you still need a nicely structured app, but all logic/code is in your projetct's files then.
Most rules for your data involve more complex constraints as the databse can do (ie: only allow user if birthday above 1998), which makes code-side constraints unavoidable, why then do both if you already have code-side constriants? And yes, in a perfect univers we would have perfect constraints, but reality has a project that changed hands 10 times and was constantly developed over 5 years.

Comment: If there is a constraint you need to enforce on the data, the DB can handle it, no matter how complex it is. The only time it won't is possibly when you're using dynamic variables that are not stored in DBs, but these are cases for which something like a JS based validation is performed.

Also, your example of 10 devs over 5 years is exactly why DB based constraints help. Multiple access points in your application written over the years can make it a nightmare to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is better to utilize foreign key constraints like cascade. It is simple, efficient and consistent.

Something like this on your Album table

```
FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES User(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This would delete all entries in the Album table that reference a particular 'id' in the user table, as soon as the 'id' row in the User table is deleted.